# VBA Excel calculating slowly

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro which is taking a long time to process. The main reason for this is a loop which is populating a range with a formula.

To speed things up I used the autofill function on a range in order to populate the formula faster. This works, however when I run the macro I need to press shift+F9 in order to update the formula.

For Excel to process the calculations it is taking 20 minutes, while it takes just 20 seconds to populate the range with the formula.

Is there any workaround to make Excel update the formulas faster?

I have tried breaking down the range and using the activesheet.calculation function but it slows everything down.

```
Sheets("Sheet").Range(CL1 & i.Row).Formula = "=ROUND(IF(Trim(Left(" & CL1 & "$2,4))="""",""Missing Value"",IF($B" & i.Row & "=""Sheet1"",SUMIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&$B" & i.Row & "&""'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(trim(left(" & CL1 & "$2,4))&"" - Total"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")&"":""&" & _ "SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(trim(left(" & CL1 & "$2,4))&"" - Total"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")),INDIRECT(""'""&$B" & i.Row & "&""'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$3,Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")&"":""& " & _ "SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$3,Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")),$C" & i.Row & ",INDIRECT(""'""&$B" & i.Row & "&""'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($D$3,Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")&"":""&" & _ "SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($D$3,Sheet2!$1:$1,0),4),""1"","""")),$D" & i.Row & "),IF($B" & i.Row & "=""SOI"",IFERROR(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(""'SOI'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C" & i.Row & ", Sheet3!$1:$1,0)+2,4),""1""," & """"") & "":"" &SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C" & i.Row & ",SOI!$1:$1,0)+2,4),""1"","""")),INDIRECT(""'SOI'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C" & i.Row & ",SOI!$1:$1,0)+0,4),""1"","""") & "":"" &SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1," & _ "MATCH($C" & i.Row & ",Sheet4!$1:$1,0)+0,4),""1"","""")),Trim(Left(" & CL1 & "$2,4)),INDIRECT(""'SOI'!""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C" & i.Row & ", Sheet3!$1:$1,0)+1,4),""1"","""") & "":"" &SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C" & i.Row & ",SOI!$1:$1,0)+1," & "4),""1"","""")),$D" & i.Row & "),""Classification Error""),if(B" & i.Row & "=""Unrealised"",INDEX(INDIRECT($B" & i.Row & "&""!A:ZZ""),MATCH($D" & i.Row & ",INDIRECT($B" & i.Row & "&""!A:A""),0),MATCH(trim(Left(" & CL1 & "$2,4))&"" - Movement"",INDIRECT($B" & i.Row & "&""!2:2""),0)),""Sheet Name Error"")" & _ ",if(B" & i.Row & "=""SOFP"",SUMIF(Sheet4!" & Str & ": A" & fin_Row & ", A" & i.Row & ",INDEX(Sheet3!E" & str_Row & ":" & fin_Col & fin_Row & ",0,MATCH(LEFT(" & CL1 & "$2,4), Sheet3!" & "E2:" & fin_Col & "2,0))),""Sheet Name Error""))),)"
```

Comment: Simplify the formula or calculate the values in your code instead of using formulas. But there's no code or formula in the question, so what answer do you expect?

Comment: Hi Brak, the code is from work and all confidential - sorry. My question relates more to how Excel updates formulas and is there a faster way.

Comment: Then show a simplified version with different data and field names, so that we can see the concept.

Comment: There may well be a much faster way of accomplishing what you want to do, but since you cannot share anything more about your goals, data, code, etc., there's not much I can do to help.  In general, doing all the calculations within a VBA array, and then populating the range with the results, will run orders of magnitude more quickly than what you are probably doing now.  And there are plenty of examples showing that on the SO website.

Comment: Interesting Ron, the problem is these formulas need to be dynamic, therefore calculating in a vba array is not possible, because a subsequent change would not be captured on the worksheet. Sorry I cannot show the code, I do not even have it on my home. The major point here is that the moment Excel has to calculate the sheet, it takes up to a half an hour. Ideally I could auto fill the formulas with the code already in it. Still, I am beginning to understand that perhaps the code is too convoluted. I think I can show a modified version.

Comment: You are using INDIRECT which is Volatile.  This means that EVERY formula with INDIRECT will recalculate anytime a cell is changed.  As said above there is definitly a better way to do what you want to acheive , if you provide the right details and remember if your having to use "MANUAL" calculation on a workbook, then the design is wrong ,  The Excel Calculation Chain is a beautiful thing when you realise how it works and how fast it really is.

Comment: @Lowpar You can always trigger the calculation with a button, or even with a worksheet_change event.  And Steven Martin's comment about `INDIRECT` is also something to consider.

Comment: Ok, that code is scary - but that is what you made it so that you could paste it in. Can you show us the earlier version., or what it tools like once it is in Excel, - us humans just can't parse that!   There has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: The code is scary, I did not write it, It is basically retrieving different values from different sheets based on criterion. Does anyone have any ideas about how to use something other than INDIRECT? I can understand now why it is taking so long to calculate, there are 382,800, so every time a cell changes it is recalculating. OMG!

Answer (score 1):

If you can disable the update of the screen  and calculations during the loop, it will considerably improve performance, especially if each formula insert forces the rest to recalculate.

Comment: Hi Mike, these functions are already disabled, it is more to do with updating the formulas after they are embedded in the cells, when I use autofill it adds the function but the value from the cell above, I need to update the values once the formula is in the cells.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the data and the formulae that you are inserting?

Comment: There may be a different method of delivering what you need. Alternatively, have you tried to populate the range from the bottom up? (It shouldn't make a difference if calculate is turned off, but interesting to check)

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is completely confidential, I am not even allowed take it from the workplace. I will try populating from the bottom up and revert.